# How to create new document reference for runTransaction in react (firebase)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a new doc in firebase/firestore, in runTransaction function of firebase in react. But I don't know how to create a reference for new doc in react firebase?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../../css/centerLoader.css";
import { MainFlexLoader } from "../CenterLoader";

import { auth } from "../../firebase-config";
import { db } from "../../firebase-config";

import { collection, doc, runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Records() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const initailizeData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      // here I want to add new document with transaction
      await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
        let newRecordRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "record",);
        transaction.set(newRecordRef, {
          amount: 1000,
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initailizeData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <MainFlexLoader />;

  return <div className="main"></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to add a document with a random ID then try:

```
const newRecordRef = doc(collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "record"));
```

If you want to specify your own ID, then use `doc()` itself:

```
const newRecordRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "record", "custom-record-id"));
```